# cannot find name 'ChartOptions'

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, bar-chart, apexcharts

in Angular i'm using     "chart.js": "^3.9.1",  getting error
`ERROR in node_modules/chart.js/types/adapters.d.ts:1:15 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ChartOptions'.`

```
1 import type { ChartOptions } from './index.esm';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/chart.js/types/adapters.d.ts:1:30 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'from'.

1 import type { ChartOptions } from './index.esm';
                               ~~~~
node_modules/chart.js/types/adapters.d.ts:14:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ChartOptions'.

14   init(chartOptions: ChartOptions): void;
```

trying to use datalabels in chart js but i have import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

```
    let myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: number,
        datasets:  [{
          categoryPercentage: 1,
        label: "IncomingCalls",
        data: callsReceived,
        borderColor: '#4c8ffb',
        backgroundColor: '#4c8ffb',
        borderWidth: 2,
        barThickness: 50},
        {
          categoryPercentage: 1,
        label: "OutgoingCalls",
        data:callmade,
        borderColor: '#58e395',
        backgroundColor: '#58e395',
        borderWidth: 2,
        barThickness: 50}],
          
      },

      options:{
      scales: {
          xaxis:{
            stacked:true,
          },
        
        
      } ,
      plugins: {
        //  datalabels:{
        //    formatter:(value , ctx)=>{
        //      console.log(ctx.chart.data);
        //    }
        //  },

        title: {
            display: true,
            text: this.graphTitle
        }
    }
       },
//plugins:[chartDataLabels]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install this package `@types/chart.js`:

```
npm i -D @types/chart.js
```

It'll solve the issue.

Comment: Still getting the same error installed     "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.37",

Comment: tried import  chartDataLabels from'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels'; import  * as chartDataLabels from'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';